# Oracle - How to Create Table with Two Columns that grow like 2D array?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a table for logging purpose in such a way that when I will insert into table I have an Execution order column that increment per RequestID-wise.

```
CREATE TABLE WSRequestLog
    (
        RequestId NUMBER,
        ExecOrder INTEGER,
        MobileNo VARCHAR2(50),
        CardNo VARCHAR2(50),
        Log_Text VARCHAR2(4000),
        DateTime date
        PRIMARY KEY (RequestId, ExecOrder)
    );


PROCEDURE Generate
.
.
.
    IF first_condition = TRUE THEN

        INSERT INTO WSRequestLog (RequestId, ExecOrder, MobileNo, CardNo, Log_Text, DateTime)
        VALUES (v_req_id, Auto_Incremenet or NextVal, v_mobile_no, v_card_no, 'Performing First Step', SYSDATE);
        --Execute Code
        IF second_condition = TRUE THEN

            INSERT INTO WSRequestLog (RequestId, ExecOrder, MobileNo, CardNo, Log_Text,DateTime)
            VALUES (v_req_id, Auto_Incremenet or NextVal, v_mobile_no, v_card_no, 'First Step executed, checking next step', SYSDATE);  
            --Execute Code
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO WSRequestLog (RequestId, ExecOrder, MobileNo, CardNo, Log_Text,DateTime)
            VALUES (v_req_id, Auto_Incremenet or NextVal, v_mobile_no, v_card_no, 'Second Step not applicable', SYSDATE);
            --Execute Code
        END IF;

    END IF;

END Generate;
```

My question is how to achieve this type of insertion?
So that if I execute the Stored Procedure, the log table would be like this:

[image: For Demonstration purpose]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Your "Generate" procedure would have to pass execution order into the insert, or just use a sequence, and if all you care about is getting records back in the proper order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a package which is pragma serially reusable which will have one variable set to null. 
In other package which contains core logger code, verify if the variable is null then set request id variable value - which is a package variable- You will increment this value in your case. for exec order follow the logic as in below lines

procedure set_log_sequence(p_log_sequence in number) as 
 begin 
   if p_log_sequence is null then 
           gv_log_sequence := gv_log_seq; 
     gv_log_seq := gv_log_seq+1; 
   else 
           gv_log_sequence := p_log_sequence; 
   end if; 
 end;